# Android Subscriptions charge user flow

Tags: android

After read all documentation and examples, I still have open questions regarding user charge process:

1. Do Google Play Market send any callback to client after every successful charge with appropriate order id and other billing details?
2. Is it possible to configure subscription with only one trial period?
   (If user will cancel subscription and then subscribe again for the
   same sku, we don't want to give him trial again)

Thanks in advance